# Responsive div without effecting Center div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```
    <div id="leftdiv" style="height:200px;width:15%;float:left"></div>
<div id="centerdiv" style="height:200px;width:70%;float:left"></div>
<div id="rightdiv" style="height:200px;width:15%;float:left"></div>
```

these are three div
i need responsiveness in leftdiv and rightdiv but centerdiv remain in same position

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. - https://jsfiddle.net/6m2ne08k/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6m2ne08k/3/

Comment: Your Jsfiddle doesn't explain what the actual **problem** is.

Comment: Your question is as unclear as my toilet at 8 am in the morning. Please provide some additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is lacking any real explanation of what the actual problem is *but* based on your demo link it seems that you are trying to overide inline styles.

This is not really possible with plain CSS as inline styles nearly always win specificity wars.

Best to move the styles into the stylesheet as a base style and then alter based on media queries.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#leftdiv {
  background: red;
  width: 15%;
}
#centerdiv {
  background: blue;
  width: 70%;
}
#rightdiv {
  background: green;
  width: 15%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #leftdiv {
    background: red;
    width: 5%;
  }
  #centerdiv {
    background: blue;
    width: 90%;
  }
  #rightdiv {
    background: green;
    width: 5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="leftdiv"></div>
<div id="centerdiv"></div>
<div id="rightdiv"></div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6m2ne08k/4/)